# How to return a 3D array of integers from a function to be used in another function in C?

Tags: c, arrays, function, return

I made this function to split any matrix into smaller-in-dimension ones, it will be used in another function which in its turn will continue doing calculations on the "container" array via using a for loop (cycling through it)
I need to know how to return the "container" array correctly to be used in another function (not in the main function), taking into account the the parameter in this function comes from another function.
So this function will receive an array from another function then split it and pack it in a 3D array then return it to be used in the function the parameter that came from

```
int split_matrix(int matrix[][COL3]){
int row2, col2, row3, col3, row1, col1 , row , col , x , unwanted_col;
int container[COL3][COL3-1][COL3-1];
for (x =0, unwanted_col = 0 ; x < COL3 ; x++ , unwanted_col++){
    for (row2 = 0 , row3=0; row3 < COL3 ; row3++ ){
         for (col2=0, col3 =0; col3 < COL3; col3++){
             if (row3!=0 && col3 !=unwanted_col){
                container[x][row2][col2]= matrix[row3][col3] ;
                     col2++;
                          if (col2 == (COL3-1)){row2++;}
              }
          }
       }
}
return ?? ;}
```

The container 3D array will be used in this function
this function will receive a 2D array from the user input (the main function) as a parameter, then will pass this array to the above function and after that use the return value from the above function (container 3D array in this case) and continue working on it, how can I extract the all the elements from the (container 3D array) in the above function and use them here.

```
void function_name(int matrix[][COL3]){
// for loop goes here to cycle through the return array and print every single element in the matrix return from the first function
```

how can I do a correct return and how can I use it in the second function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you want to return `container`, there no possible way at the moment as it's a local variable inside the function and will go out of scope once the function returns.

You have basically only two possible solutions: Use dynamic allocation for all levels of the array, and return a pointer (to a pointer to a pointer), but note that being a [three star programmer](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ThreeStarProgrammer) is not considered a compliment).

The other solution is to declare the array of arrays of arrays in the calling function, and pass it to the function in an argument, and then the function can use it. This is the solution I would recommend, and the function prototype would then look something like

```
void function_name(int matrix[][COL3], int (*container)[COL3-1][COL3-1]);
```

Comment: @John So pass it just the same way to the second function?

Comment: @John So the function you show is not called from the `main` function? But the function that should use the `container` array *is* called from the `main` function, and the `main` function only? Crucial information is very important to state in the question body, and not as comments. It's also why it's so important to make a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to show us, or else all we can do is guess and assume. Also please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).